# Making code thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, callable

I am trying to see if this code is thread safe.

```
private void eventProcessing(final AcEvent acEvent){
    String tree = null;
    String symbol = null;

    try {
        if(acEvent.isDatafileTransaction()){
            final AcEventDatafileTransaction datafileTransaction = acEvent.getDatafileTransaction();
            tree = datafileTransaction.getTreeId();
            symbol = datafileTransaction.getSymbol();
            System.out.println(tree, symbol);
        }
    }
```

Do I need to make methods in *AcEvent* or *ACEventDatafileTransaction* synchronized. Both these classes just have only *get* methods as you saw in the code. I am thinking regardless of the number of threads, it will not have a problem in accessing the right values for tree and symbol. Can I say this code is thread safe or do I need to make any changes to make it thread safe?

I am putting eventprocessing in Callable

```
threadpool.submit(new Callable<Integer>(){
    public Integer call() throws Exception{
        eventProcessing(event);
    }
});
```

**EDIT :**
These are two lines after what I have written in eventprocessing.

```
 final List<AcStreamAble> transactions = getDatafileTransactions(datafileTransaction);
 final List<AcEventRecordOperation> recordOperations = getTransactionsAsListOfRecordOperations(datafileTransaction, transactions);
```

I am adding a couple of methods that will come next. Tell me if this will change anything.

```
 private List<AcEventRecordOperation> getTransactionsAsListOfRecordOperations(final AcEventDatafileTransaction datafileTransaction, final List transactions) {
            final List <AcEventRecordOperation> recordOperations = new ArrayList<AcEventRecordOperation>(transactions.size());
            int i = 0;
            for (final Object o : transactions) {
                if (!datafileTransaction.isRecordOperation(o)) {
                    log.debug( "[" + i + "] Ignored transaction - was not a RecordOperation" );
                } else {
                    recordOperations.add(datafileTransaction.convert(o));
                }
            }
            return recordOperations;
        }
```

In the above method, even though there is a list and objects are added to it. I am thinking since it an internal variable, it will be thread safe.

```
    private List<AcStreamAble> getDatafileTransactions(final AcEventDatafileTransaction datafileTransaction) throws IOException {
        final List<AcStreamAble> transactions = new ArrayList<AcStreamAble>();
        datafileTransaction.addTransactions(transactions);
        return transactions;
    }
```

Here since datafileTransaction object is different for different threads. I am assuming it is thread safe.

Comment: As you are not modifying any thing apart from local variables, it looks OK.  BTW *If a final variable holds a reference to an object, then the state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the variable will always refer to the same object*

Comment: But each thread will have its own final variable right referring to its own object ?

Comment: I would imagine so.  Event processing usually works that way

Comment: If you're not changing `event` anywhere then it's safe.

Comment: I am assuming the edited part is also threadsafe because these are all internal variables and objects used to access external methods are different for each thread.